# Pyspark cannot load from pathlib object

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

```
Python Version 3.7.5
Spark Version 3.0
Databricks Runtime 7.3
```

I'm currently working with paths in my datalake file system.

This is

```
p = dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi')
print(p)
 [FileInfo(path='dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/readme_nyctaxi.txt', name='readme_nyctaxi.txt', size=916),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/reference/', name='reference/', size=0),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/taxizone/', name='taxizone/', size=0),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/tripdata/', name='tripdata/', size=0)]
```

now, to turn this into a valid Pathlib Posix Object I pass this through a function

```
def create_valid_path(paths):
    return Path('/dbfs').joinpath(*[part for part in Path(paths).parts[1:]])
```

the output for `tripdata` is

```
PosixPath('/dbfs/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/tripdata')
```

now, if I want to read this into a sparkdata frame after collecting a subset of csvs into a list.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
df = spark.read.format('csv').load(paths)
```

this returns

```
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

now, the only way I can get this to work is to manually prepend the path `dbfs:/..` and return each item to a string however it's necessary to use Pathlib to do some basic I/O operations. am I missing something simple or can Pyspark simply not read a pathlib object?

e.g

```
trip_paths_str = [str(Path('dbfs:').joinpath(*part.parts[2:])) for part in trip_paths]

print(trip_paths_str)

['dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/tripdata/fhv/fhv_tripdata_2015-01.csv.gz',
 'dbfs:/databricks-datasets/nyctaxi/tripdata/fhv/fhv_tripdata_2015-02.csv.gz'...]
```

Comment: Do you need a colon after `dbfs` (e.g., `dbfs:/part1/parts2`) in your pathlib objects?

Comment: @PaulH this works only if I force it into a string, but is similar to my own work around which pre-pends this `dbfs:/` (sorry missed the `/` in my post) and returns a string. This and still begs requires me to first create a valid pathlib object then a valid pyspark file path to read into a spark dataframe.

Comment: sounds like you need to break up your code into chunks 1) use pathlib objets to do your basic IO, convert those pathlib objects to pyspark paths via a custom function you need to write, 3) do your pyspark stuff

Comment: @PaulH thanks - just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something due to my in-experience - i'll leave the question open maybe someone from the Microsoft team can give more clarity.

Comment: Generally pyspark does not recognize Path objects.  This fails: 
    `dbutils.fs.ls(Path('dbfs:/FileStore/plots/lce_all'))    
    TypeError: PosixPath('dbfs:/FileStore/plots/lce_all') has the wrong type - (<class 'str'>,) is expected.` 
 but, just pass the string and it succeeds: 
    `dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/FileStore/plots/lce_all')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about doing this then instead?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 
import os

def db_list_files(file_path):
  file_list = [file.path for file in dbutils.fs.ls(file_path) if os.path.basename(file.path)]
  return file_list

files = db_list_files('dbfs:/FileStore/tables/')
 
df = spark.read.format('text').load(files)
df.show()
```

Comment: Yes I get that, but sometime you need to work around and that is why I say What about doing this then? May be I should have added instead.

Comment: In terms of big data processing that speed would be negligible. There area lot of nuances on the databricks side.